# Windows Update has stopped working

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

My PC was being a bit weird - trying to save files in IE11 wasn't working - so I did a virus scan (no results) and thought I'd better make sure I was up to date with patches. When I tried to launch Windows Update, it hung, so I had to restart my PC.

Now when I try to run it, I get this:

[image]

I've already checked that the service is running, and tried restarting the service (as well as the PC): no change.

I already tried renaming c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution and re-starting the service so a new copy is created - that happens but the problem doesn't resolve.

I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong and how I'm supposed to fix it. My W7 installation has always been pretty solid until now.

Comment: There's a Windows Update Fixit, a Troubleshooter and various other tools on MS' site. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Never heard of them... can you provide this as an answer (with links and any further information)?

Comment: Links? [Here](https://www.google.com/?q=windows+update+problems) you go, check out the first few results. I'm sure they've all been mentioned in many previous answers here. Ideally though this sort of query is best suited to a forum because it necessitates back and forth of logs and so on.

Comment: I already did that which is how I found the 'solutions' I already tried - that's why I mentioned them. You just find thousands of forum posts of people making suggestions and no way to tell who knows what they're talking about - hence coming to SE to find someone who does, and doesn't just tell me to Google it!

Comment: So if you already did what's listed in the top-most results *from Microsoft* to that query, then how come you didn't run any Fixit or Troubleshooter? Those are precisely what those result pages offer.

Comment: Because when I searched for the _error message_ I receive, nothing useful came up other than MS support/forum posts. I figured any number of things can go wrong with update... and none of the forum posts I found referenced any of those tools, even the advice from MS people.

Comment: A generic search query can often be more useful than an extremely specific one. Anyway can you now try those tools at least and edit your question to include the results?

Comment: Yeah, will do that